# How to take direct print from iPhone to HP Laserjet Printers?

Tags: iphone, printing

I have a HP laserjet printer installed in my office. The printer is connected to my office LAN and I connected my iPhone to the WiFi router to access internet and that WiFi modem is connected directly to the office LAN. Now I want to take printouts from my phone directly to the HP Laserjet printer. How it's possible? Do I need to download any software or extra apps to take direct print from this so called Apple Smartphone?

Comment: Exact printer model #?  Router model #?  One or the other would need to support AirPrint.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need software on the iOS device, but you do need a device like the [Lantronix xPrintServer](http://www.lantronix.com/it-management/xprintserver/xprintserver-t2.html) to smarten up old printers that don't speak the new AirPrint language.

Most new printers speak AirPrint out of the box, but older printers need help learning new tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the new HP LaserJet printers are mostly AirPrint enabled. Apple publish a [list of supported AirPrint](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4356) printers.

I can recommend Apple App Store wise, [PrintCentral](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/printcentral/id366020849?mt=8), or [Print n Share](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/print-n-share-pro-iphone/id471501333?mt=8); both of which I have installed on my iPad and iPhone.